# Deleting duplicates from single-linked list

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there a way to modify linked list that way so we delete all duplicates from it.

The think is it needs to be done for linear time and constant memory usage. I tried to put all elements of the list into `HashMap` which gives us constant time but linear memory usage.

Is there another way?

Comment: It can't be done.

Comment: What is wrong with linear memory usage? If you want constant memory usage, then you need n^2 operations to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stream().distinct()` method to do it for linear time:

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That is far from being constant memory usage. And it doesn't even modify the list. It creates another one.

Comment: And yes, it's possible to do it in linear time. That's what your code does.

Comment: @JBNizet My mistake. Thank you for your correction.

Comment: Or just `Set<Whatever> noDups = new LinkedHashSet<>(listWithDups);`

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically it sounds impossible (or someone here will surprise me).

but you can create a simulation of a list without duplicates without really make any algorithm that way:

```
public class SimulatedNoDuplicatesList extends LinkedList {
    private List originalList;
    SimulatedNoDuplicatesList(List original) {
        originalList = original;
    }
// override all the methods that you want to use with the old list. for example
//   @Override
    public Object get(int i) {
        if (!super.contains(i) && originalList.contains(i)) {
            super.add(originalList.get(i));
        }
        return super.get(i);
    }
}
```